# Show progress dialog inside thread 2017

Tags: android, progressdialog

I read some posts about this topic and I tried like this:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(String s) {
Log.d("TestFFmpeg", "SUCCESS with output : " + s);
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
progressDialog.setTitle("Server request");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.setMessage("Waiting response from server...");
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
try {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                  progressDialog.show();
             }
        });
        final Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                      progressDialog.dismiss();
                 }
            });
}
```

I mention that I used the same progress dialog in the class and I dissmissed it.

If I run the application like this I receive this error:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token null is not for an application

What should I change?

Comment: change initialization to `progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dialog` requires Activity context.

Change `ProgressDialog` initialization to

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Wow It worked! I don't know how I missed that..thanks!